# Import error for tensorflow, why is this happening?

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgVBc.jpg)

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     61   try:
---> 62     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     63   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: Module use of python310.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     35 import typing as _typing
     36 
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     38 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     39 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     34 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     35 
---> 36 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     37 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     38 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     76 except ImportError:
     77   raise ImportError(
---> 78       f'{traceback.format_exc()}'
     79       f'\n\nFailed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.\n'
     80       f'See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors '

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: Module use of python310.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common causes and solutions.
If you need help, create an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues and include the entire stack trace above this error message.

Comment: How did you install tensorflow in your system? You can follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install tensorflow by checking the Software and Hardware requirements in your system.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict in the Python version as the error clearly suggests.

There are 2 versions installed on the same system.

It is desirable to install the suitable python version while you do run the conda create command :

```
conda create -n tf python=3.10 anaconda
#Activate environment 
activate tf
#Install Tensorflow
conda install tensorflow==2.13
```